# The table is full when insert records by php program (around 15m)

Tags: mysql, table, database-size

```
    Error: INSERT INTO tbl_xxxxxx ( .........);
    The table 'tbl_invoice_detail_lesson' is full
```

I have checked lots of article, most of them are noticed that it has to change the max_heap_table_size, tmp_table_size, and max_rows of the table.

And then the table is truncate and start the program, when the table row grows near 10m records, it starts to flow 'The Table xxx is full' in some insertion scripts(But other records can be inserted afterwards).

This error will flow after around 2000 rows once.

```
    The below is the my config:
    Window Server 2016 
    RAM: 7.71GB
    64-bit OS
    MYSQL Server 5.7 Win32

   max_connections=151
   table_open_cache=200000
   thread_cache_size=10000
   myisam_max_sort_file_size=1000G
   myisam_sort_buffer_size=64M
   key_buffer_size=1024M
   read_buffer_size=8192
   read_rnd_buffer_size=1
   innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
   innodb_log_buffer_size=64M
   innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G
   innodb_log_file_size=512M
   innodb_thread_concurrency=8
   innodb_autoextend_increment=64
   innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8
   innodb_concurrency_tickets=5000
   innodb_old_blocks_time=1000
   innodb_open_files=300
   innodb_stats_on_metadata=0
   innodb_file_per_table=1
   innodb_checksum_algorithm=0
   back_log=80
   flush_time=0
   join_buffer_size = 1024M
   max_allowed_packet=4M
   max_connect_errors=100
   open_files_limit=4161
   sort_buffer_size=64M
   table_definition_cache=1400
   binlog_row_event_max_size=8K
   sync_master_info=10000
   sync_relay_log=10000
   sync_relay_log_info=10000
   net_write_timeout = 6000
   net_read_timeout = 3000
   innodb_page_size = 16384
   innodb_page_cleaners = 16
   max_heap_table_size = 8G
   tmp_table_size=8G
   innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:12M:autoextend:max:8G

   Mysql > Show table status;
   # Name, Engine, Version, Row_format, Rows, Avg_row_length, Data_length, Max_data_length, Index_length, Data_free, Auto_increment, Create_time, Update_time, Check_time, Collation, Checksum, Create_options, Comment
   'tbl_invoice_detail_lesson', 'InnoDB', '10', 'Dynamic', '15455046', '148', '2292187136', '0', '3805609984', '4194304', '15572231', '2018-04-26 12:05:28', '2018-04-26 17:33:27', NULL, 'utf8_general_ci', NULL, 'max_rows=1000000000', ''
```

This problem will cause when I restart the MYSQL, and then do any operation on that table. It will lost the connection immediately.
And the log is:

```
    InnoDB: Trying to access page number 263280 in space 69, space name db_yyyy/tbl_xxxxx, which is outside the tablespace bounds. Byte offset 0, len 16384, i/o type read. If you get this error at mysqld startup, please check that your my.cnf [truncated, 316 bytes total]
```

Please let me know if there is any I can do.
Thanks.

```
   Further Information (Update: 19-06-2018)
   # Variable_name, Value
    Innodb_buffer_pool_dump_status, Dumping of buffer pool not started
    Innodb_buffer_pool_load_status, Buffer pool(s) load completed at 180619  6:03:36
    Innodb_buffer_pool_resize_status, 
    Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data, 460
    Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data, 7536640
    Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty, 0
    Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty, 0
    Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed, 42
    Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free, 2608
    Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc, 4
    Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total, 3072
    Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd, 0
    Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead, 0
    Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted, 0
    Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests, 8341
    Innodb_buffer_pool_reads, 426
    Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free, 0
    Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests, 385
    Innodb_data_fsyncs, 7
    Innodb_data_pending_fsyncs, 0
    Innodb_data_pending_reads, 0
    Innodb_data_pending_writes, 0
    Innodb_data_read, 7049728
    Innodb_data_reads, 453
    Innodb_data_writes, 59
    Innodb_data_written, 722944
    Innodb_dblwr_pages_written, 2
    Innodb_dblwr_writes, 1
    Innodb_log_waits, 0
    Innodb_log_write_requests, 0
    Innodb_log_writes, 2
    Innodb_os_log_fsyncs, 4
    Innodb_os_log_pending_fsyncs, 0
    Innodb_os_log_pending_writes, 0
    Innodb_os_log_written, 1024
    Innodb_page_size, 16384
    Innodb_pages_created, 35
    Innodb_pages_read, 425
    Innodb_pages_written, 42
    Innodb_row_lock_current_waits, 0
    Innodb_row_lock_time, 0
    Innodb_row_lock_time_avg, 0
    Innodb_row_lock_time_max, 0
    Innodb_row_lock_waits, 0
    Innodb_rows_deleted, 0
    Innodb_rows_inserted, 132
    Innodb_rows_read, 140
    Innodb_rows_updated, 0
    Innodb_num_open_files, 19
    Innodb_truncated_status_writes, 0
    Innodb_available_undo_logs, 128
    Key_blocks_not_flushed, 0
    Key_blocks_unused, 229551
    Key_blocks_used, 3
    Key_read_requests, 6
    Key_reads, 3
    Key_write_requests, 0
    Key_writes, 0
    Locked_connects, 0
    Max_execution_time_exceeded, 0
    Max_execution_time_set, 0
    Max_execution_time_set_failed, 0
    Max_used_connections, 4
    Max_used_connections_time, 2018-06-19 06:03:37
    Not_flushed_delayed_rows, 0
    Ongoing_anonymous_transaction_count, 0
    Open_files, 15
    Open_streams, 0
    Open_table_definitions, 108
    Open_tables, 112
    Opened_files, 157
    Opened_table_definitions, 108
    Opened_tables, 119
    Performance_schema_accounts_lost, 0
    Performance_schema_cond_classes_lost, 0
    Performance_schema_cond_instances_lost, 0
    Performance_schema_digest_lost, 0
    Performance_schema_file_classes_lost, 0
    Performance_schema_file_handles_lost, 0
    Performance_schema_file_instances_lost, 0
    Performance_schema_hosts_lost, 0
    Performance_schema_index_stat_lost, 0
    Performance_schema_locker_lost, 0
    Performance_schema_memory_classes_lost, 0
    Performance_schema_metadata_lock_lost, 0
    Performance_schema_mutex_classes_lost, 0
    Performance_schema_mutex_instances_lost, 0
    Performance_schema_nested_statement_lost, 0
    Performance_schema_prepared_statements_lost, 0
    Performance_schema_program_lost, 0
    Performance_schema_rwlock_classes_lost, 0
    Performance_schema_rwlock_instances_lost, 0
    Performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_lost, 0
    Performance_schema_socket_classes_lost, 0
    Performance_schema_socket_instances_lost, 0
    Performance_schema_stage_classes_lost, 0
    Performance_schema_statement_classes_lost, 0
    Performance_schema_table_handles_lost, 0
    Performance_schema_table_instances_lost, 0
    Performance_schema_table_lock_stat_lost, 0
    Performance_schema_thread_classes_lost, 0
    Performance_schema_thread_instances_lost, 0
    Performance_schema_users_lost, 0
    Prepared_stmt_count, 0
    Qcache_free_blocks, 1
    Qcache_free_memory, 515944
    Qcache_hits, 0
    Qcache_inserts, 0
    Qcache_lowmem_prunes, 0
    Qcache_not_cached, 11
    Qcache_queries_in_cache, 0
    Qcache_total_blocks, 1
    Queries, 81
    Questions, 78
    Select_full_join, 0
    Select_full_range_join, 0
    Select_range, 0
    Select_range_check, 0
    Select_scan, 82
    Slave_open_temp_tables, 0
    Slow_launch_threads, 0
    Slow_queries, 0
    Sort_merge_passes, 0
    Sort_range, 0
    Sort_rows, 0
    Sort_scan, 0
    Ssl_accept_renegotiates, 0
    Ssl_accepts, 0
    Ssl_callback_cache_hits, 0
    Ssl_cipher, 
    Ssl_cipher_list, 
    Ssl_client_connects, 0
    Ssl_connect_renegotiates, 0
    Ssl_ctx_verify_depth, 0
    Ssl_ctx_verify_mode, 0
    Ssl_default_timeout, 0
    Ssl_finished_accepts, 0
    Ssl_finished_connects, 0
    Ssl_server_not_after, 
    Ssl_server_not_before, 
    Ssl_session_cache_hits, 0
    Ssl_session_cache_misses, 0
    Ssl_session_cache_mode, NONE
    Ssl_session_cache_overflows, 0
    Ssl_session_cache_size, 0
    Ssl_session_cache_timeouts, 0
    Ssl_sessions_reused, 0
    Ssl_used_session_cache_entries, 0
    Ssl_verify_depth, 0
    Ssl_verify_mode, 0
    Ssl_version, 
    Table_locks_immediate, 137
    Table_locks_waited, 0
    Table_open_cache_hits, 33
    Table_open_cache_misses, 119
    Table_open_cache_overflows, 0
    Tc_log_max_pages_used, 0
    Tc_log_page_size, 0
    Tc_log_page_waits, 0
    Threads_cached, 0
    Threads_connected, 4
    Threads_created, 4
    Threads_running, 1
    Uptime, 60
    Uptime_since_flush_status, 60


# Variable_name, Value
'auto_increment_increment', '1'
'auto_increment_offset', '1'
'autocommit', 'ON'
'automatic_sp_privileges', 'ON'
'avoid_temporal_upgrade', 'OFF'
'back_log', '80'
'basedir', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.7\\'
'big_tables', 'OFF'
'bind_address', '*'
'binlog_cache_size', '32768'
'binlog_checksum', 'CRC32'
'binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates', 'OFF'
'binlog_error_action', 'ABORT_SERVER'
'binlog_format', 'ROW'
'binlog_group_commit_sync_delay', '0'
'binlog_group_commit_sync_no_delay_count', '0'
'binlog_gtid_simple_recovery', 'ON'
'binlog_max_flush_queue_time', '0'
'binlog_order_commits', 'ON'
'binlog_row_image', 'FULL'
'binlog_rows_query_log_events', 'OFF'
'binlog_stmt_cache_size', '32768'
'block_encryption_mode', 'aes-128-ecb'
'bulk_insert_buffer_size', '8388608'
'character_set_client', 'latin1'
'character_set_connection', 'latin1'
'character_set_database', 'latin1'
'character_set_filesystem', 'binary'
'character_set_results', 'latin1'
'character_set_server', 'latin1'
'character_set_system', 'utf8'
'character_sets_dir', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.7\\share\\charsets\\'
'check_proxy_users', 'OFF'
'collation_connection', 'latin1_swedish_ci'
'collation_database', 'latin1_swedish_ci'
'collation_server', 'latin1_swedish_ci'
'completion_type', 'NO_CHAIN'
'concurrent_insert', 'AUTO'
'connect_timeout', '10'
'core_file', 'OFF'
'datadir', 'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.7\\Data\\'
'date_format', '%Y-%m-%d'
'datetime_format', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'
'default_authentication_plugin', 'mysql_native_password'
'default_password_lifetime', '0'
'default_storage_engine', 'InnoDB'
'default_tmp_storage_engine', 'InnoDB'
'default_week_format', '0'
'delay_key_write', 'ON'
'delayed_insert_limit', '100'
'delayed_insert_timeout', '300'
'delayed_queue_size', '1000'
'disabled_storage_engines', ''
'disconnect_on_expired_password', 'ON'
'div_precision_increment', '4'
'end_markers_in_json', 'OFF'
'enforce_gtid_consistency', 'OFF'
'eq_range_index_dive_limit', '200'
'event_scheduler', 'OFF'
'expire_logs_days', '0'
'explicit_defaults_for_timestamp', 'OFF'
'flush', 'OFF'
'flush_time', '0'
'foreign_key_checks', 'ON'
'ft_boolean_syntax', '+ -><()~*:\"\"&|'
'ft_max_word_len', '84'
'ft_min_word_len', '4'
'ft_query_expansion_limit', '20'
'ft_stopword_file', '(built-in)'
'general_log', 'OFF'
'general_log_file', 'EC2AMAZ-V797AQA.log'
'group_concat_max_len', '1024'
'gtid_executed', ''
'gtid_executed_compression_period', '1000'
'gtid_mode', 'OFF'
'gtid_owned', ''
'gtid_purged', ''
'have_compress', 'YES'
'have_crypt', 'NO'
'have_dynamic_loading', 'YES'
'have_geometry', 'YES'
'have_openssl', 'DISABLED'
'have_profiling', 'YES'
'have_query_cache', 'YES'
'have_rtree_keys', 'YES'
'have_ssl', 'DISABLED'
'have_statement_timeout', 'YES'
'have_symlink', 'YES'
'host_cache_size', '279'
'hostname', 'EC2AMAZ-V797AQA'
'ignore_builtin_innodb', 'OFF'
'ignore_db_dirs', ''
'init_connect', ''
'init_file', ''
'init_slave', ''
'innodb_adaptive_flushing', 'ON'
'innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm', '10'
'innodb_adaptive_hash_index', 'ON'
'innodb_adaptive_hash_index_parts', '8'
'innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay', '150000'
'innodb_api_bk_commit_interval', '5'
'innodb_api_disable_rowlock', 'OFF'
'innodb_api_enable_binlog', 'OFF'
'innodb_api_enable_mdl', 'OFF'
'innodb_api_trx_level', '0'
'innodb_autoextend_increment', '64'
'innodb_autoinc_lock_mode', '1'
'innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size', '50331648'
'innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown', 'ON'
'innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now', 'OFF'
'innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct', '25'
'innodb_buffer_pool_filename', 'ib_buffer_pool'
'innodb_buffer_pool_instances', '1'
'innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort', 'OFF'
'innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup', 'ON'
'innodb_buffer_pool_load_now', 'OFF'
'innodb_buffer_pool_size', '50331648'
'innodb_change_buffer_max_size', '25'
'innodb_change_buffering', 'all'
'innodb_checksum_algorithm', 'crc32'
'innodb_checksums', 'ON'
'innodb_cmp_per_index_enabled', 'OFF'
'innodb_commit_concurrency', '0'
'innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct', '5'
'innodb_compression_level', '6'
'innodb_compression_pad_pct_max', '50'
'innodb_concurrency_tickets', '5000'
'innodb_data_file_path', 'ibdata1:10M:autoextend'
'innodb_data_home_dir', ''
'innodb_deadlock_detect', 'ON'
'innodb_default_row_format', 'dynamic'
'innodb_disable_sort_file_cache', 'OFF'
'innodb_doublewrite', 'ON'
'innodb_fast_shutdown', '1'
'innodb_file_format', 'Barracuda'
'innodb_file_format_check', 'ON'
'innodb_file_format_max', 'Barracuda'
'innodb_file_per_table', 'ON'
'innodb_fill_factor', '100'
'innodb_flush_log_at_timeout', '1'
'innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit', '1'
'innodb_flush_method', ''
'innodb_flush_neighbors', '1'
'innodb_flush_sync', 'ON'
'innodb_flushing_avg_loops', '30'
'innodb_force_load_corrupted', 'OFF'
'innodb_force_recovery', '0'
'innodb_ft_aux_table', ''
'innodb_ft_cache_size', '8000000'
'innodb_ft_enable_diag_print', 'OFF'
'innodb_ft_enable_stopword', 'ON'
'innodb_ft_max_token_size', '84'
'innodb_ft_min_token_size', '3'
'innodb_ft_num_word_optimize', '2000'
'innodb_ft_result_cache_limit', '2000000000'
'innodb_ft_server_stopword_table', ''
'innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree', '2'
'innodb_ft_total_cache_size', '640000000'
'innodb_ft_user_stopword_table', ''
'innodb_io_capacity', '200'
'innodb_io_capacity_max', '2000'
'innodb_large_prefix', 'ON'
'innodb_lock_wait_timeout', '50'
'innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog', 'OFF'
'innodb_log_buffer_size', '23068672'
'innodb_log_checksums', 'ON'
'innodb_log_compressed_pages', 'ON'
'innodb_log_file_size', '50331648'
'innodb_log_files_in_group', '2'
'innodb_log_group_home_dir', '.\\'
'innodb_log_write_ahead_size', '8192'
'innodb_lru_scan_depth', '1024'
'innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct', '75.000000'
'innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm', '0.000000'
'innodb_max_purge_lag', '0'
'innodb_max_purge_lag_delay', '0'
'innodb_max_undo_log_size', '1073741824'
'innodb_monitor_disable', ''
'innodb_monitor_enable', ''
'innodb_monitor_reset', ''
'innodb_monitor_reset_all', ''
'innodb_old_blocks_pct', '37'
'innodb_old_blocks_time', '1000'
'innodb_online_alter_log_max_size', '134217728'
'innodb_open_files', '300'
'innodb_optimize_fulltext_only', 'OFF'
'innodb_page_cleaners', '1'
'innodb_page_size', '16384'
'innodb_print_all_deadlocks', 'OFF'
'innodb_purge_batch_size', '300'
'innodb_purge_rseg_truncate_frequency', '128'
'innodb_purge_threads', '4'
'innodb_random_read_ahead', 'OFF'
'innodb_read_ahead_threshold', '56'
'innodb_read_io_threads', '4'
'innodb_read_only', 'OFF'
'innodb_replication_delay', '0'
'innodb_rollback_on_timeout', 'OFF'
'innodb_rollback_segments', '128'
'innodb_sort_buffer_size', '1048576'
'innodb_spin_wait_delay', '6'
'innodb_stats_auto_recalc', 'ON'
'innodb_stats_include_delete_marked', 'OFF'
'innodb_stats_method', 'nulls_equal'
'innodb_stats_on_metadata', 'OFF'
'innodb_stats_persistent', 'ON'
'innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages', '20'
'innodb_stats_sample_pages', '8'
'innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages', '8'
'innodb_status_output', 'OFF'
'innodb_status_output_locks', 'OFF'
'innodb_strict_mode', 'ON'
'innodb_support_xa', 'ON'
'innodb_sync_array_size', '1'
'innodb_sync_spin_loops', '30'
'innodb_table_locks', 'ON'
'innodb_temp_data_file_path', 'ibtmp1:12M:autoextend'
'innodb_thread_concurrency', '8'
'innodb_thread_sleep_delay', '9'
'innodb_tmpdir', ''
'innodb_undo_directory', '.\\'
'innodb_undo_log_truncate', 'OFF'
'innodb_undo_logs', '128'
'innodb_undo_tablespaces', '0'
'innodb_use_native_aio', 'ON'
'innodb_version', '5.7.21'
'innodb_write_io_threads', '4'
'interactive_timeout', '28800'
'internal_tmp_disk_storage_engine', 'InnoDB'
'join_buffer_size', '1073741824'
'keep_files_on_create', 'OFF'
'key_buffer_size', '268435456'
'key_cache_age_threshold', '300'
'key_cache_block_size', '1024'
'key_cache_division_limit', '100'
'keyring_operations', 'ON'
'large_files_support', 'ON'
'large_page_size', '0'
'large_pages', 'OFF'
'lc_messages', 'en_US'
'lc_messages_dir', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.7\\share\\'
'lc_time_names', 'en_US'
'license', 'GPL'
'local_infile', 'ON'
'lock_wait_timeout', '31536000'
'log_bin', 'OFF'
'log_bin_basename', ''
'log_bin_index', ''
'log_bin_trust_function_creators', 'OFF'
'log_bin_use_v1_row_events', 'OFF'
'log_builtin_as_identified_by_password', 'OFF'
'log_error', '.\\EC2AMAZ-V797AQA.err'
'log_error_verbosity', '3'
'log_output', 'FILE'
'log_queries_not_using_indexes', 'OFF'
'log_slave_updates', 'OFF'
'log_slow_admin_statements', 'OFF'
'log_slow_slave_statements', 'OFF'
'log_statements_unsafe_for_binlog', 'ON'
'log_syslog', 'ON'
'log_syslog_tag', ''
'log_throttle_queries_not_using_indexes', '0'
'log_timestamps', 'UTC'
'log_warnings', '2'
'long_query_time', '10.000000'
'low_priority_updates', 'OFF'
'lower_case_file_system', 'ON'
'lower_case_table_names', '1'
'master_info_repository', 'FILE'
'master_verify_checksum', 'OFF'
'max_allowed_packet', '4194304'
'max_binlog_cache_size', '18446744073709547520'
'max_binlog_size', '1073741824'
'max_binlog_stmt_cache_size', '18446744073709547520'
'max_connect_errors', '100'
'max_connections', '151'
'max_delayed_threads', '20'
'max_digest_length', '1024'
'max_error_count', '64'
'max_execution_time', '0'
'max_heap_table_size', '83886080'
'max_insert_delayed_threads', '20'
'max_join_size', '18446744073709551615'
'max_length_for_sort_data', '1024'
'max_points_in_geometry', '65536'
'max_prepared_stmt_count', '16382'
'max_relay_log_size', '0'
'max_seeks_for_key', '4294967295'
'max_sort_length', '1024'
'max_sp_recursion_depth', '0'
'max_tmp_tables', '32'
'max_user_connections', '0'
'max_write_lock_count', '4294967295'
'metadata_locks_cache_size', '1024'
'metadata_locks_hash_instances', '8'
'min_examined_row_limit', '0'
'multi_range_count', '256'
'myisam_data_pointer_size', '6'
'myisam_max_sort_file_size', '10737418240'
'myisam_mmap_size', '4294967295'
'myisam_recover_options', 'OFF'
'myisam_repair_threads', '1'
'myisam_sort_buffer_size', '67108864'
'myisam_stats_method', 'nulls_unequal'
'myisam_use_mmap', 'OFF'
'mysql_native_password_proxy_users', 'OFF'
'named_pipe', 'OFF'
'net_buffer_length', '16384'
'net_read_timeout', '30000'
'net_retry_count', '10'
'net_write_timeout', '60000'
'new', 'OFF'
'ngram_token_size', '2'
'offline_mode', 'OFF'
'old', 'OFF'
'old_alter_table', 'OFF'
'old_passwords', '0'
'open_files_limit', '402209'
'optimizer_prune_level', '1'
'optimizer_search_depth', '62'
'optimizer_switch', 'index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,engine_condition_pushdown=on,index_condition_pushdown=on,mrr=on,mrr_cost_based=on,block_nested_loop=on,batched_key_access=off,materialization=on,semijoin=on,loosescan=on,firstmatch=on,duplicateweedout=on,subquery_materialization_cost_based=on,use_index_extensions=on,condition_fanout_filter=on,derived_merge=on'
'optimizer_trace', 'enabled=off,one_line=off'
'optimizer_trace_features', 'greedy_search=on,range_optimizer=on,dynamic_range=on,repeated_subselect=on'
'optimizer_trace_limit', '1'
'optimizer_trace_max_mem_size', '16384'
'optimizer_trace_offset', '-1'
'parser_max_mem_size', '4294967295'
'performance_schema', 'ON'
'performance_schema_accounts_size', '-1'
'performance_schema_digests_size', '10000'
'performance_schema_events_stages_history_long_size', '10000'
'performance_schema_events_stages_history_size', '10'
'performance_schema_events_statements_history_long_size', '10000'
'performance_schema_events_statements_history_size', '10'
'performance_schema_events_transactions_history_long_size', '10000'
'performance_schema_events_transactions_history_size', '10'
'performance_schema_events_waits_history_long_size', '10000'
'performance_schema_events_waits_history_size', '10'
'performance_schema_hosts_size', '-1'
'performance_schema_max_cond_classes', '80'
'performance_schema_max_cond_instances', '-1'
'performance_schema_max_digest_length', '1024'
'performance_schema_max_file_classes', '80'
'performance_schema_max_file_handles', '32768'
'performance_schema_max_file_instances', '-1'
'performance_schema_max_index_stat', '-1'
'performance_schema_max_memory_classes', '320'
'performance_schema_max_metadata_locks', '-1'
'performance_schema_max_mutex_classes', '210'
'performance_schema_max_mutex_instances', '-1'
'performance_schema_max_prepared_statements_instances', '-1'
'performance_schema_max_program_instances', '-1'
'performance_schema_max_rwlock_classes', '40'
'performance_schema_max_rwlock_instances', '-1'
'performance_schema_max_socket_classes', '10'
'performance_schema_max_socket_instances', '-1'
'performance_schema_max_sql_text_length', '1024'
'performance_schema_max_stage_classes', '150'
'performance_schema_max_statement_classes', '193'
'performance_schema_max_statement_stack', '10'
'performance_schema_max_table_handles', '-1'
'performance_schema_max_table_instances', '-1'
'performance_schema_max_table_lock_stat', '-1'
'performance_schema_max_thread_classes', '50'
'performance_schema_max_thread_instances', '-1'
'performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_size', '512'
'performance_schema_setup_actors_size', '-1'
'performance_schema_setup_objects_size', '-1'
'performance_schema_users_size', '-1'
'pid_file', 'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.7\\Data\\EC2AMAZ-V797AQA.pid'
'plugin_dir', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.7\\lib\\plugin\\'
'port', '3306'
'preload_buffer_size', '32768'
'profiling', 'OFF'
'profiling_history_size', '15'
'protocol_version', '10'
'query_alloc_block_size', '16384'
'query_cache_limit', '524288'
'query_cache_min_res_unit', '4096'
'query_cache_size', '524288'
'query_cache_type', 'OFF'
'query_cache_wlock_invalidate', 'OFF'
'query_prealloc_size', '8192'
'range_alloc_block_size', '4096'
'range_optimizer_max_mem_size', '8388608'
'rbr_exec_mode', 'STRICT'
'read_buffer_size', '8192'
'read_only', 'OFF'
'read_rnd_buffer_size', '1'
'relay_log', ''
'relay_log_basename', 'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.7\\Data\\EC2AMAZ-V797AQA-relay-bin'
'relay_log_index', 'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.7\\Data\\EC2AMAZ-V797AQA-relay-bin.index'
'relay_log_info_file', 'relay-log.info'
'relay_log_info_repository', 'FILE'
'relay_log_purge', 'ON'
'relay_log_recovery', 'OFF'
'relay_log_space_limit', '0'
'report_host', ''
'report_password', ''
'report_port', '3306'
'report_user', ''
'require_secure_transport', 'OFF'
'rpl_stop_slave_timeout', '31536000'
'secure_auth', 'ON'
'secure_file_priv', 'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.7\\Uploads\\'
'server_id', '1'
'server_id_bits', '32'
'server_uuid', 'f7f95d78-3e3d-11e8-9383-029e743fb328'
'session_track_gtids', 'OFF'
'session_track_schema', 'ON'
'session_track_state_change', 'OFF'
'session_track_system_variables', 'time_zone,autocommit,character_set_client,character_set_results,character_set_connection'
'session_track_transaction_info', 'OFF'
'sha256_password_proxy_users', 'OFF'
'shared_memory', 'OFF'
'shared_memory_base_name', 'MYSQL'
'show_compatibility_56', 'OFF'
'show_old_temporals', 'OFF'
'skip_external_locking', 'ON'
'skip_name_resolve', 'OFF'
'skip_networking', 'OFF'
'skip_show_database', 'OFF'
'slave_allow_batching', 'OFF'
'slave_checkpoint_group', '512'
'slave_checkpoint_period', '300'
'slave_compressed_protocol', 'OFF'
'slave_exec_mode', 'STRICT'
'slave_load_tmpdir', 'C:\\Windows\\SERVIC~2\\NETWOR~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp'
'slave_max_allowed_packet', '1073741824'
'slave_net_timeout', '60'
'slave_parallel_type', 'DATABASE'
'slave_parallel_workers', '0'
'slave_pending_jobs_size_max', '16777216'
'slave_preserve_commit_order', 'OFF'
'slave_rows_search_algorithms', 'TABLE_SCAN,INDEX_SCAN'
'slave_skip_errors', 'OFF'
'slave_sql_verify_checksum', 'ON'
'slave_transaction_retries', '10'
'slave_type_conversions', ''
'slow_launch_time', '2'
'slow_query_log', 'ON'
'slow_query_log_file', 'EC2AMAZ-V797AQA-slow.log'
'socket', 'MySQL'
'sort_buffer_size', '16777216'
'sql_auto_is_null', 'OFF'
'sql_big_selects', 'ON'
'sql_buffer_result', 'OFF'
'sql_log_off', 'OFF'
'sql_mode', 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
'sql_notes', 'ON'
'sql_quote_show_create', 'ON'
'sql_safe_updates', 'OFF'
'sql_select_limit', '18446744073709551615'
'sql_slave_skip_counter', '0'
'sql_warnings', 'OFF'
'ssl_ca', ''
'ssl_capath', ''
'ssl_cert', ''
'ssl_cipher', ''
'ssl_crl', ''
'ssl_crlpath', ''
'ssl_key', ''
'stored_program_cache', '256'
'super_read_only', 'OFF'
'sync_binlog', '1'
'sync_frm', 'ON'
'sync_master_info', '10000'
'sync_relay_log', '10000'
'sync_relay_log_info', '10000'
'system_time_zone', 'Coordinated Universal Time'
'table_definition_cache', '1400'
'table_open_cache', '200000'
'table_open_cache_instances', '16'
'thread_cache_size', '10000'
'thread_handling', 'one-thread-per-connection'
'thread_stack', '196608'
'time_format', '%H:%i:%s'
'time_zone', 'SYSTEM'
'tls_version', 'TLSv1,TLSv1.1'
'tmp_table_size', '83886080'
'tmpdir', 'C:\\Windows\\SERVIC~2\\NETWOR~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp'
'transaction_alloc_block_size', '8192'
'transaction_isolation', 'REPEATABLE-READ'
'transaction_prealloc_size', '4096'
'transaction_read_only', 'OFF'
'transaction_write_set_extraction', 'OFF'
'tx_isolation', 'REPEATABLE-READ'
'tx_read_only', 'OFF'
'unique_checks', 'ON'
'updatable_views_with_limit', 'YES'
'version', '5.7.21-log'
'version_comment', 'MySQL Community Server (GPL)'
'version_compile_machine', 'AMD64'
'version_compile_os', 'Win32'
'wait_timeout', '28800'
```

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_invoice_detail_lesson`.  It sounds like you have unnecessary indexes.

Comment: @user3423149  Providing this could be helpful in answering your question.

Comment: I see the `SHOW VARIABLES`; thanks.  The `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` has two problems (1) the first part is lost, and (2) it was after the server was up only one minute; please wait a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestions to consider for your my.cfg-ini [mysqld] section

You have ~ 8 GB RAM but you have asked for

```
. myisam_max_sort_file_size=           1000G
. key_buffer_size=1024M         that is   1G
. join_buffer_size-1024M        another   1G
. max_heap_table_size=8G        another   8G
. and
. tmp_table_size=8G      shared space
.                               Total  1010G requested in your ini.

table_open_cache=10000  # from 200000  for a reasonable limit
thread_cache_size=100  # from 10000  CAP V8 refman to avoid OOM
innodb_page_cleaners=8  # from 16 to be = innodb_buffer_pool_instances
max_heap_table_size=80M  # from 8G for 1% of RAM
tmp_table_size=80M  # from 8G for the shared 1% of RAM
```

and REMOVE (to allow defaults to work of you, until you NEED capacity)

```
. myisam_max_sort_file_size
. innodb_page_size
. key_buffer_size
. read_buffer_size
. read_rnd_buffer_size
. join_buffer_size
. sort_buffer_size
```

Take 2 minutes and use www.mysqlcalculator.com to see what you have asked for in terms of RAM footprint with your requested values.

Good luck.

Comment: @user3423149 Thanks for the Accepted.  How is your instance running now?  Is use of this 'tbl_invoice_detail_lesson' still causing disconnect?
If you would post (on pastebin.com or here) text results of   SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; and   SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;  additional helpful Suggestions will be provided to improve instance performance.

Comment: I would take some things down even more:  `table_open_cache = 1000` and `thread_cache_size = 20`

Comment: @rickjames  Hoping user..... will post after 7 days of uptime  A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;  and B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;  to allow more knowledge than just guessing at GV needs.

Comment: Yes, there can be some interesting surprises in the variables/statuses

Comment: @user3423149 Can you share with us how your instance is running now?  If you would post (on pastebin.com or here) text results of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; and SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; additional helpful Suggestions will be provided to improve instance performance.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Hi, I have lower down some parameters like the page size and page cleaner. And the running instance is stable right now(I hope it is). 
I guess the problem is the insertion program is running too fast, there is the records insertion during the table expansion but I am not sure about this.

Comment: @user3423149  Thanks for your feedback.   If you would post (on pastebin.com or here) when UPTIME is 7 days or more, text results of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; and SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; additional helpful Suggestions will be provided to improve instance performance.  Have a great weekend.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I am sorry that when I re-import the data into the database, the same error coming out. The record size is about 6M rows (I have checked the file size of ibd file is 4194304KB).

Comment: @RickJames I have also update the SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; and SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; in the question. Thanks

Comment: @user3423149  Please post to pastebin.com text results of A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;  B) complete content of my.cnf-ini.  The only thing similar to GLOBAL STATUS is for 60 seconds and is only a part of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;.  Need 7 days of UPTIME to be more meaningful.  HOW much RAM do you have?  Complete report from Mysqltuner.pl would be helpful.

Comment: @user3423149   Please FLUSH LOGS  and post your error log so we can see the message from the re-import problem.

Comment: @user3423149 We now see you have ~ 8GB RAM.  Please post to pastebin.com or here text results of A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; B) complete content of my.cnf-ini. Need 7 days of UPTIME to be more meaningful.  Complete report from Mysqltuner.pl would be helpful.  With this information we can more accurately guide your effort towards reliability.

Answer (score 0):

4194304KB is exactly 2^32.  MySQL has no such limit, but something seems to be stopping you there.  However, there is one thing that you *could* be setting:

```
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:12M:autoextend:max:8G
```

Do you really want to stop the disk allocation at 8G?  If so, let's discuss it.  I suggest you change that to

```
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:12M:autoextend
```

and restart MySQL (mysqld).

No, I can't explain the factor of 2 discrepancy between 4194304KB and max:8G.  But it is clearly an issue.

Oh!  Here's a baddie:

```
'version_compile_os', 'Win32'
```

I did not think that would limit ibdata to 4G, but it is highly suspect.  Upgrade to a 64-bit version!

(Yes, I agree with Wilson's recommendation of removing the changes to the various settings -- some of them could cause severe slowdowns, possibly even crashes other than the one you are asking about.)

Comment: You are right. In the meanwhile, I am upgrading the mysql to 64 bit version to see same issue will happen or not. I wonder why there are so much differents in 32 bit and 64 bit version. I will keep you update the status. Thanks much.

Comment: @user3423149 Please add new items to your Question after 7 days or more of uptime, what is there today is OLD and only 60 seconds of uptime.  We know you are busy.  Please post to pastebin.com text results of A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; C) complete content of my.cnf-ini. HOW much RAM do you have? Complete report from Mysqltuner.pl would be helpful. Thanks for working through this effort.